# How to Use all processor cores for x64 application

Tags: c#, cpu-cores

I have got a simple code for compare two arrays:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String directory = @"C:\path\";
        String[] linesA = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "array1.txt"));
        String[] linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "array2.txt"));

        var onlyB = linesA.Where(a => linesB.Any(b => a.ToLower().Contains(b.ToLower())));

        File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "Result.txt"), onlyB);
    }
```

Is there any method to use all cores of processor to compare those two arrays?

Comment: What is the problem? If is obvious your code is not using more memory. Want to WASTE memory, do it.

Comment: So there is not any method to compare it faster?

Comment: There certainly is, but it would involve coming up with a good algorithm as opposed to the O(n^2) scan.

Comment: It will be troublesome to have an application reserve all the RAM if it's just going to compare two arrays.

Comment: I don't understand, why app does not uses more computer resources to compare arrays faster, when it can.

Comment: Because your task is CPU bound. There is no need to waste more memory if processor already cannot cope. Arguably, simply changing your lambda to `linesA.Where(a => linesB.Any(b => a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0))` will speed it up to some degree. In your particular case you could also use [Parallel LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to make sure you use all CPU and not just one core.

Comment: Faster and using more memory has nothing to do with each other. Want faster? Learn about parallelfor and use multiple threads. That was not your question, though - you load all data into memory, more memory won't help. Not being stupid will. Like.... make the ToLower ONCE for both arrays, instead of doing it repeatedly. And consider why ToLower is WRONG - ToUpper would be better. There is a question here in stackoverflow about it. Try search.

Comment: One simple way to speed this up is to avoid doing `ToLower()` on the strings multiple times by using `string.IndexOf()` like so: `var onlyB = linesA.Where(a => linesB.Any(b => a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));`

Comment: I changed question. First was wrong because I thought that speed of compare depends of RAM memory. Now I know it depends of processor speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually want to speed this up (rather than just use more memory) there are a few things you can to.

1. Instead of using `File.ReadAllLines()` for both files (which reads the entire file into memory), use `File.ReadLines()` for the file used in the outer loop. This will only read that file line-by-line and avoid a potentially large amount of memory use.
2. Instead of using ToLower() on the strings multiple times, use `string.IndexOf()` like so: `var onlyB = linesA.Where(a => linesB.Any(b => a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));`
3. Use `.AsParallel()` to parallelise part of the loop.

Putting this all together:

```
var linesA = File.ReadLines(Path.Combine(directory, "array1.txt"));
var linesB = File.ReadAllLines(Path.Combine(directory, "array2.txt"));

Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

var onlyB = linesA.AsParallel().Where(a => linesB.Any(b => a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

After making these changes, my test program went from taking ~3.8s to ~0.6s, and used a lot less memory.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code is much faster then mine, it uses almost 100% of processor and 5,2MB of RAM (!) memory. Mine code uses only one core of processor and 1360MB of RAM memory.